Is it possible to have multiple rotating images for the background of a Sharepoint custom branded login form?
Hi I already have a sharepoint site but I am looking to add some customizations. Can you please let me know if the following is possible?
CSS override so instead of the instead of the static background image I would like to have it be a rotating gallery of the images from the clients portfolio?

Are you talking about Microsoft 365 default login page branding? I don't think you can fully customize this page. However, you can try adding GIF image as "background image" and see if it works for you. Let me know if it works.
